# java: how to loop that i get exactly 3^10 (disjunct)values in 3 columns?

Tags: java, permutation

I want to make a list of 3 values of the following kind (binary notation!):

```
0;0;0  
1;0;0  
0;1;0  
11;0;0
10;1;0 
  .
  .
  . 
1111111111;0;0 
0;1111111111;0 
0;0;1111111111
```

and all missing values in between

this list means: all columns have to have all values(permutations?), but only if the bit is not set in another column

this is the problem of putting 10 markable things into 3 different boxes

i tried 3 loops but i always mess it up :(
thats what i have so far:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class create_referencevalues {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long[] list = { 10L, 40L, 90L, 160L, 250L, 350L, 500L, 650L,800L,1000L };

        try {
            java.io.PrintStream p = new java.io.PrintStream(
                    new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(
                            new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(
                                    "C:/users/djdeejay/listall.csv"), false)));
            for (Integer i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
                Long sum1 = 0L;
                for (Integer j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    if (BigInteger.valueOf(i).testBit(j)) {
                        sum1 += (list[j]);
                    }

                }
                sum1 *= Integer.bitCount(i);
                Long sum2 = 0L;
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    if (BigInteger.valueOf(1023 - i).testBit(j)) {
                        sum2 += (list[j]);
                    }
                }
                sum2 *= 10-Integer.bitCount(i);

                p.println(i +";"+ Long.toBinaryString(i)+";" + sum1+";"+ Long.toBinaryString(1023-i)+";"+sum2);
            }

            p.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

how do i integrate a loop wich gives me the 3rd row and all permutations between the rows ?
thanks for any help

Comment: Please clarify a little more on what you mean by 3 column permutation.

Comment: Ok, I haven't thought of the exact solution but I can tell you that, using recursion will be convenient here. Although any recursive code can be written in loop structure, still some solutions are way more elegant if implemented using recursion. You may think of solution in this regard.

Comment: If you want to be disassociated from a post (or all your posts), then you can ask SO through the contact page to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/contact Don't just replace your post with gibberish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class Permutation {

    private static final int NB_DIGITS = 10;

    private int[] DIGIT_NUMBER = {1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000, 1000000000};

    public void dump(PrintStream printStream) {
        int[] counter = new int[NB_DIGITS];
        Arrays.fill(counter, 0);
        do {
            int column1 = 0;
            int column2 = 0;
            int column3 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < NB_DIGITS; i++) {
                int columnIdx = counter[i];
                switch (columnIdx) {
                    case 0 : column1+=DIGIT_NUMBER[i];break;
                    case 1 : column2+=DIGIT_NUMBER[i];break;
                    case 2 : column3+=DIGIT_NUMBER[i];break;
                    default:
                        assert false;
                }

            }

            printStream.format("%d;%d;%d%n", column1, column2, column3);

        } while (increase(counter));
    }

    public boolean increase(int[] counter) {
        int idx = 0;
        while (idx < counter.length && counter[idx] == 2) {
            counter[idx] = 0;
            idx++;
        }

        if (idx == counter.length) {
            return false;
        }

        counter[idx]++;
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Permutation().dump(System.out);
    }
}
```

The counter array contains the column index where to put your digits. This is actually a loop by hand in base 3 between 0 and 3^10-1 so you reach all the possible positions.

Comment: @djdeejay this is faster mainly because in your solution you test 1024^3 combinations and reject most of them (as you said there are only 3^10=59049 valid combinations). In my method I loop only on the valid ones, so less iterations (around 18000 time less) and no test.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:
loop all three rows by all values and mask values you dont want:
if (((k & j) == 0) && ((k & i) == 0) && ((j & i) == 0) && (k^j^i)==max)
that means: a bit at a position must be set only in one row and the rows together must have set all bits

```
package com.djdeejay.cowTrade.client.standaloneplayer.application;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class create_referencevalues {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long[] list = { 10L, 40L, 90L, 160L, 250L, 350L, 500L, 650L, 800L,
                1000L };

        try {
            java.io.PrintStream p = new java.io.PrintStream(
                    new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(
                            new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(
                                    "C:/users/djdeejay/listall.csv"), false)));
            Long i = 0l;
            Long j = 0l;
            Long k = 0l;
            Long max = 1023L;
            Long count = 0l;
            for (i = 0l; i < max; i++) {
                for (j = 0l; j < max; j++) {
                    for (k = 0l; k < max; k++) {
                        String col1 = Long.toBinaryString(i);
                        String col2 = Long.toBinaryString(j);
                        String col3 = Long.toBinaryString(k);
                        if (((k & j) == 0) && ((k & i) == 0)
                                && ((j & i) == 0) && (k^j^i)==max) {
                            count++;
                            Long sum1 = 0L, sum2 = 0L, sum3 = 0L;
                            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                                if (BigInteger.valueOf(i).testBit(x)) {
                                    sum1 += (list[x]);
                                }
                                if (BigInteger.valueOf(j).testBit(x)) {
                                    sum2 += (list[x]);
                                }
                                if (BigInteger.valueOf(k).testBit(x)) {
                                    sum3 += (list[x]);
                                }
                            }
                            sum1 *= Long.bitCount(i);
                            sum2 *= Long.bitCount(j);
                            sum3 *= Long.bitCount(k);
                            p.println(count + ";" + i + ";" + j + ";" + k);
                            System.out.println(count + ";" + col1 + ";" + col2 + ";" + col3);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count + ";" + i + ";" + j + ";" + k);

            p.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```